# Error with Embed a Form in ActiveCampaign Email Campaigns

Tags: email-attachments, embedding, activecampaign

I'm currently working on an email campaign using ActiveCampaign and facing a challenge with embedding a form directly into the email body. I have a form hosted on ActiveCampaign and I want to embed it within the email so recipients can fill it out directly from their inbox.

Here's the embed code provided by ActiveCampaign for my form:

```
<div class="_form_9"></div>
<script src="https://mysite.activehosted.com/f/embed.php?id=9" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I tried inserting this code into my HTML email template, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. The form does not appear in the email when I send a test email to myself.

I understand that many email clients have limited support for forms and scripts for security reasons. However, I've read that ActiveCampaign might have specific support for this.

My questions are:

Is there a specific way to embed ActiveCampaign forms in email campaigns that I might be missing?
Are there any known compatibility issues with certain email clients when it comes to embedding forms in emails?
If direct embedding is not possible, what are the best practices or alternatives to achieve a similar user experience?
Any insights or examples of successfully embedding ActiveCampaign forms in emails would be greatly appreciated!